# Nested Package: AttributeError: module 'app' has no attribute

Tags: python

I'm just learning python, coming from a C# & Java background, and I'm pretty confused by the import system.  Just trying to run a simple test for learning purposes, but getting an error AttributeError: module 'app' has no attribute 'example'

See code below, can someone explain why the error is thrown?  I only seem to encounter this issue when there's a package inside a package, as seen in the instance of package "example" contained inside package "app"

**run.py**

```
import app
```

**app/__init__.py**

```
import app.example
```

**app/example/__init__.py**

```
import app.example.a
```

**app/example/a.py**

```
import app.example.b
print("TESTING: " + str(app.example.b)) #error is thrown on this line
```

**app/example/b.py**

```
print("LOADED B")
```

**Error Thrown:**

```
"C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\npwc-services\Scripts\python.exe" C:/Users/xxxxxxxx/PycharmProjects/untitled1/run.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
LOADED B
  File "C:/Users/xxxxxxxx/PycharmProjects/untitled1/run.py", line 1, in <module>
    import app
  File "C:\Users\xxxxxxxx\PycharmProjects\untitled1\app\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    import app.example
  File "C:\Users\xxxxxxxx\PycharmProjects\untitled1\app\example\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    import app.example.a
  File "C:\Users\xxxxxxxx\PycharmProjects\untitled1\app\example\a.py", line 2, in <module>
    print("TESTING: " + str(app.example.b))
AttributeError: module 'app' has no attribute 'example'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

**Directory Structure:**

[image]

Comment: Try `import .example` in `app/__init__.py`, and follow this with other modules and packages as well. You want relative, not absolute imports inside a package.

Comment: Thanks I didn't know relative imports were possible till you mentioned it, but the exact syntax you provided didn't work for me with Python 3.

I had to do something like this instead: from .example.app import a

Comment: correction, i ended up using from . import example which seems to be directly equivalent to what you provided in your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

run.py

```
import app
```

app/**init**.py

```
from .example.app import a # or b or ...
```