# Flask AttributeError: module 'app' has no attribute 'run'

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, flask, python-import

My Flask project is structured as follows:

```
my_project
│
├── app
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── api
│   ├── static
│   └── templates
├── config.py
└── run.py
```

**app/__init__.py**:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config.from_object('config')
```

**run.py**

```
from app import app

app.run(
    host=app.config.get('HOST', '0.0.0.0'),
    port=app.config.get('PORT', 5000)
)
```

This worked before, but I'm trying to migrate my project from Python 2 to Python 3, and running `python run.py` no longer works. I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/rasmi/Projects/my_project/run.py", line 3, in <module>
    app.run(
AttributeError: module 'app' has no attribute 'run'
```

If I change the import style in `run.py` to match the one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33839796/nested-package-attributeerror-module-app-has-no-attribute):

```
from .app import app

app.run(
    host=app.config.get('HOST', '0.0.0.0'),
    port=app.config.get('PORT', 5000)
)
```

I get a different error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/rasmi/Projects/my_project/run.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .app import app
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.app'; '__main__' is not a package
```

Wrapping my `app.run()` call in an `if __name__ == '__main__':` block yields the same results. What's causing this issue?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I fixed this issue by renaming the `app` directory to something else (e.g. `webapp`). Using `from webapp import app` does the trick. This seems to be because [package directory names take precedence over module names when importing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16245345/950845). Perhaps using `__path__` would allow one to get around this.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this issue by doing this in my `runserver.py`:

```
from WebApp import app 
app.app.run(debug=True)
```

Where the name of the package is Webapp. Noticed how I used `app` twice. Also, my Flask app is called `app`.

```
├── WebApp
│   ├── app.py
│   ├── authentication.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── models.py
├── runserver.py
```

Answer (score 1):

I was facing same issue for below line in my app,

```
import app.main.constant.constants as Constants
```

but then I restructure above command to below, and It worked for me.

```
from app.main.constant import constants as Constants
```

Answer (score 0):

can you change your `from app import app1` to `from app import *`?

it worked for me

```
<code>
├── app
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── viewss.py
├── run.py
</code>
```

I was trying to import app from `app/init__.py` in run.py